# How to access n dimensional array using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I set x is array contains several variables with are inputs of a evaluation function. Each 
 variable has limit defined in `xBoundary[index][min,max]`. Each possible variable value has step size `xStep[]`.

e.g. `x[0]` is between `0` and `10` since `xBoundary[0][0]=0` and `xBoundary[0][1]=10`. `xStep[0]=0.5` then x has possible value `0,0.5,1,1.5,.....9.5,10`.
How can I access all possible value of x? I think this is a n dimensional array where `n = length of x`.

The following is my code. It is infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define nx_SIZE 2                   // dimension of x

double x[nx_SIZE] = {0};                     // Initialize x
double xBoundary[nx_SIZE][2]={{0,5},{2,5}};  //Contains lower and upper boundary of x.
                                             //xBoundary[][0]=min
                                             //xBoundary[][1]=max
double xStep[nx_SIZE]={1};                   //Step size for variable in x.

void iterate(int dimension) {


  int i = dimension - 1;
  double currentX, upperLimit;

  if (i == -1){

    printf("x: %f %f \n", x[0], x[1]);
    //evaluate();

  } else {

    currentX = xBoundary[i][0];
    upperLimit = xBoundary[i][1];

    while (currentX < upperLimit){
      x[i] = currentX;
      iterate(i);
      currentX = currentX + xStep[i];
    } //End of while

  }
}

int main (){

  iterate(nx_SIZE);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: For starters, 1. Format your code, 2. declare `xBoundary` as `xBoundary[nx_SIZE][2]={{0,5},{2,5}};` 3. There is a variable `demantion` undeclared in your function

Comment: Thanks. I edited the typo and format. @brokenfoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is caused by  `double xStep[nx_SIZE]={1};`. This only assign `xStep[0]` value to `1` and rest are `0`. The zero increment cause infinite loop.

Value of x is n dimensional array where `n = length of x`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define nx_SIZE 2                              // dimension of x

double x[nx_SIZE] = {0};                       // Initialize x
double xBoundary[nx_SIZE][2]={{0,5},{2,5}};    //Contains lower and upper boundary of x.
                                               //xBoundary[][0]=min
                                               //xBoundary[][1]=max
double xStep[nx_SIZE]={1,1};                   //Step size for variable in x.
int counter = 0;                               //Number of possible x

void iterate(int dimension) {

  int i = dimension - 1;
  double currentX;

  if (i == -1){
    printf("x: %f %f \n", x[0], x[1]);
    counter++;
  } else {

    for (currentX = xBoundary[i][0]; currentX <= xBoundary[i][1]; currentX += xStep[i]) {
      x[i] = currentX;
      iterate(i);
    }

  } //End of if
} // End of iterate

int main (){

  iterate(nx_SIZE);
  printf("counter: %d", counter);
  getchar();

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, this is just a sample loop of nxSize times. try the code below(I didn't test it, you might need some updates on it)

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < nx_SIZE; i++) {
    int v;
    for (v = xBoundary[i][0]; v <= xBoundary[i][1]; v += xStep[i]) {
        printf("%f", v);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

the code above was based on nx_SIZE = 2 which is in your example, if nxSIZE is another value, you should intialize xBoundary correctly in order to make it work.